# How to prove measurability

Tags: measure-theory

How do I proof the following: $E$ is measurable if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a closed set $F$ contained in $E$ with $m_*(E-F)<\epsilon$.

Comment: What is your definition of measurability?

Comment: If you are referring to Lebesgue measure on the reals and if by $m_*$ you mean Lebesgue inner measure, it's false.

Comment: I concur with @user254665 If $E$ is a [Bernstein set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set) then $m_*(E)=0$, in particular $m_*(E-F)<\epsilon$ for any $F$ and any $\epsilon$.

Comment: OP would you clarify please, what does $m_*$ denote here, inner measure (as usual) or outer measure (usually denoted by $m^*$) ?

Comment: I am refering to the  outer measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT: I assume below that $m_*$ refers to Lebesgue exterior measure]

Closed sets are measurable, sets of zero exterior measure are measurable, and a countable (in this case, finite) union of measurable sets is measurable. Observe that $E=F\cup (E-F)$.

Comment: don't get it, isn't the problem referring to inner measure ?

Comment: I assumed the poster was using $m_*$ to refer to Lebesgue exterior (outer) measure. If $E\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, then exterior measure of E is defined to be $m_*(E)=\inf \sum_{j=1}^\infty |Q_j|$, where the inf is taken over all countable coverings of E by closed cubes $Q_j$.

Comment: "sets of zero exterior measure are measurable." How does that apply yo the proof?

Comment: It relates to the assumption in the problem. You've told us that there's a closed set F such that $m_*(E-F)<\epsilon$, i.e. $E-F$ is a set of zero exterior measure, and is hence measurable. We take the union of $F$ and $E-F$, which are both measurable, and the union is measurable. Notice that the union is exactly the set we want to show is measurable.